# how can I prevent getting focused on activity when the fragment is open on android tv?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, focus, android-tv

I have an activity that plays a movie and there are many fragments that open over the activity. when the fragment opens over activity, the activity can get focused.

I want the activity to no longer get focused when the fragment is opened over the activity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue sometimes activity get focus even fragment is open over the activity.

I couldn't able to find any direct solution but handle it my way might it helps to you.

We can `override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?)` in **Activity** but not in **Fragment** so I've add condition whenever I'm getting focus in activity, redirect that focus to current open fragment and handle manually focus in `Fragment`

Comment: Managing redirects is hard. And My Opinion about the solution isn't useful. Sometimes you may lose some focus changes because you used that to redirect actions.

Comment: May be there are some cases where focus might lose with this way but I 'm using this approach to manage focus in fragment and it works well till now for me. Have you find any better way to deal with this? I would like to know.